# I have a coding question which i have solved in python3. But i would like to know if there is better way of writing this to run faster in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am newbie to python. Recently I have tried completing a coding exercise. I did complete the coding exercise but some of test cases failed saying code took too much time probably like more than 10 sec.
I tried looking around to see how I could have code more efficiently but there is too much of info. Any help or direction is appreciated. Below are some details related to exercise.

- Jack and Jill are playing a game.

  1. Game needs a input of random integer sequence comprising of 1 and 0
     only. The input sequence can be (1,0,0,1,0) or (1,1,1,0,1,0)..
  2. Jack will have the opportunity to choose first n numbers. Jill will have to take remaining numbers in  the sequence.
  3. Scoring of game is done like this - if input value is 1 then score will increase by 1 and
     input value is 0 the score will decrease by 1.

I have to build a function which takes integer list(sequence) as input. The list can have 10^5 elements at max. Function should return minimum number of numbers Jack needed to pick from input sequence so that his score will be more that Jill.

eg: we pass input to function as [1,1,0,0,0] - minimum number of numbers Jack needed to pick is 0.

> **explanation**: if jack picks no numbers - his score will be 0. jill has to pick all the remaining 
>                    numbers. his score will be 1+1-1-1-1=-1. so function have to print 0 as output.

eg: we pass input to function as [0,1,1,0,1] - minimum number of numbers Jack needed to pick is 3.

> **explanation**: if jack picks no values then - jack's score -0 and score of Jill - -1+1+1-1+1=1.

- if jack picks one value then jack's score - -1 and  score of Jill -
  1+1-1+1=2
- if jack picks first 2 values then jack's score - 1-1 and score of
  Jill - 1-1+1=1
- if jack picks first 3 values then jack's score - 1-1+1=1 and score of
  Jill - -1+1=0

  -- 
               As you can see jack's score is more than Jill so function have to print 3 as output.

Below are 2 ways i attempted it.

```
def game(s):
    #create a new list which substitutes 0 with -1 in input list so that I am sum the values oflist.
    newlist1=[-1 if p==0 else 1 for p in s]
    if sum(newlist1)<0:
        print("the minimum amount numbers jack need to pick is: ", 0)
    else:
        for l in range(1,len(s)+1):  # main loop
            jackscore=0
            jillscore=0       
            for m in range(l):   #loop to calculate jack's score
                if s[m] == 1:
                    jackscore=jackscore+1
                else:
                    jackscore=jackscore-1
            for n in range(l,len(s)):    #loop to calculate jack's score
                if s[n] == 1:
                   jillscore=jillscore+1
                else:
                   jillscore=jillscore-1
             #for each iteration we will check if jack's score is greater than Jill      
            if jackscore>jillscore: 
                break
        print("the minimum amount numbers jack need to pick is: ",l)

#main program starts here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #y=[1,0,0,1,0]
    y = [int(x) for x in input("enter any number of 1 and 0 seperated by comma: ").split(',')]
    game(y)
```

second attempt

```
def game(s):
     #create a new list which substitutes 0 with -1 in input list so that I am sum the values oflist.
    newlist1=[-1 if p==0 else 1 for p in s]
    if sum(newlist1)<0:
        print("the minimum amount numbers jack need to pick is: ", 0)
    else:
        for l in range(1,len(s)+1):  # main loop     
            #create 2 new lists one for jack and other for Jill and sum values in list
            if sum(newlist1[:l])>sum(newlist1[l:]):
                break
        print("the minimum amount numbers jack need to pick is: ",l)

#main program starts here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #y=[1,0,0,1,0]
    y = [int(x) for x in input("enter any number of 1 and 0 seperated by comma: ").split(',')]
    game(y)
```

Are there other ways which can run faster than these one's. if yes, please help.